# WPF Textbox binding and line breaks

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox

I have a textbox that i am binding to the viewmodel's string property. The string property is updated within the viewmodel and it displays the text within the textbox through binding.

The issue is that i want to insert the line break after a certain number of characters in the string property and i want that the line break is shown over the textbox control.

I tried appending \r\n inside the string property in viewmodel but the line break is not reflected over the textbox (i have Acceptsreturn property set to true inside the textbox)

Can anybody help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a simple app that does what you describe, and it worked for me.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="50"
            Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">Button</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text = string.Empty;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return this.text; }
        set
        {
            this.text = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(null != eh)
        {
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

An instance of `ViewModel` is set as the `DataContext` for the `Window`. Finally, the implementation of `Button_Click()` is:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.model.Text = "Hello\r\nWorld";
}
```

(I realize that the view shouldn't really modify the ViewModel's `Text` property directly, but this is just a quick sample app.)

This results in the word "Hello" on the first line of the `TextBox`, and "World" is on the second line.

Maybe if you post your code we can see what is different from this sample?

Comment: Thanks Andy, i figured out the problem at my end. Thanks you very much for your support.

Answer (score 6):

The solution for me was to use HTML encoded line feeds (
).

```
Line1&#10;Line2
```

Looks like

```
Line1
Line2
```

From Naoki

Answer (score 0):

I Like @Andy Approach, it is perfect for small text not with large and scrollable text.

View Model

```
class ViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private StringBuilder _Text = new StringBuilder();
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            _Text = new StringBuilder( value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(null != eh)
        {
            eh(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    private void TextWriteLine(string text,params object[] args)
    {
        _Text.AppendLine(string.Format(text,args));
        OnPropertyChanged("Text");
    }

    private void TextWrite(string text,params object[] args)
    {
        _Text.AppendFormat(text,args);
        OnPropertyChanged("Text");
    }

    private void TextClear()
    {
        _Text.Clear();
        OnPropertyChanged("Text");
    }
}
```

Now you can use TextWriteLine, TextWrite and TextClear in your MVVM.